# Index plus character in SOLR

Tags: solr, escaping, character, uri

I am indexing some URIs in SOLR using the UAX29URLEmailTokenizerFactory tokenizer. The problem is that some of my URIs are containing plus characters, which SOLR interprets as whitespaces and splits the URI. Can this problem be solved by some clever escaping of the '+' char? I tried '+' in the analyzer, but got the same results.
Here is my exact configuration of a field:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.UAX29URLEmailTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.UAX29URLEmailTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I came up with finally makes use of the CharacterFilter as suggested above. The trick was to substitute it with the encoded char '%2B'. This had the effect of keeping the URI  as a single token and returning it to my application in a proper state - as a '+'. Here is the fieldtype definition I came up with:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="\+" replacement="%2B"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.UAX29URLEmailTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="\+" replacement="%2B"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.UAX29URLEmailTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: I tried that and for some reason, only the indexing works. The query is always passed as %2B0876xxxx, but only matches if it's %252B0876xxxx. If you're wondering, %25 seems to be the percentage escape sequence. I've not found any way to properly substitute the + so that it is respected in the search URL.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a CharacterFilter (eg. PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory) ahead of your analyzer.  This [link](http://java.dzone.com/news/solr-filters) has some good info.  One solution I can think of is replace + character with some other character - and then when you are serving this link, remember to replace it back.

Another thing to research is, replacing it with the URL encoding value of a plus (%2B), and see if analyzer treats it as a space.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, it worked great by substituting the '+' char with the escaping '%2B'